# Filter select drop down using Grails security ACL

Tags: spring, security, grails, acl

I am implementing ACL security using the spring-security-acl plugin.  I have the following domain classes:

```
package test
class Subitem {

   String name

   static belongsTo = [employer: Employer]

   static constraints = {
    name blank: false
   }
}

package test
class Employer {
   String name

   static hasMany = [users: User, items: Subitem]
   static belongsTo = User

   static constraints = {
    name blank: false, unique: true
   }

   String toString() {
    name
   }
}
```

In the create.gsp file which is used to create a Subitem, there is the following statement:

```
<g:select id="employer" name="employer.id" from="${test.Employer.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${subitemInstance?.employer?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

From the EmployerController:

```
    def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [employerInstanceList: employerService.list(params),
     employerInstanceTotal: employerService.count()]
 }
```

Following the tutorial given [here](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/single.pdf), I have moved some of the functionality with dealing with Employer to a service called EmployerService:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, read)")
List<Employer> list(Map params) {
   Employer.list params
}
int count() {
   Employer.count()
}
```

Access to information in any given Employer class instance is restricted using ACL.  At present, I can see ALL instances of Employer in the database in the drop down, and I assume that is because I am using the controller list(), not the service list() - however, I only want to see the filtered list of Employer domain classes.  However, if I replace the g:select with:

```
<g:select id="employer" name="employer.id" from="${test.EmployerService.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${subitemInstance?.employer?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

then I get an internal server error because I haven't passed a Map parameter to the service list() function (and I don't know how to do this within the  tag):

```
URI /security/subitem/create
Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message No signature of method: static test.EmployerService.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: list(java.util.Map), is(java.lang.Object), wait(), find(), wait(long), get(long)
```

I only want to see the information that comes from the EmployerService list() function - how do I do this please?  How do I reference the correct function from within the gap?

- Edit 16 Mar 0835: Thanks @OverZealous, that's really helpful, I hadn't realised that.  However, I've tried that and still get the same problem.  I've put a println() statement in both the Employer and EmployerService list() functions, and can see that neither actually seems to get called when the g:select tag is parsed (even if I leave the g:select to refer to Employer).  Is there another version of the list() function that is being called perhaps?  Or how else to get the g:select to take account of the ACL?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your method signature in the Service to look like this:

```
List<Employer> list(Map params = [:]) {
   Employer.list params
}
```

The change is adding this: `= [:]`.  This provides a default value for `params`, in this case, an empty map.

(This is a Groovy feature, BTW.  You can use it on any method or closure where the arguments are optional, and you want to provide a default.)

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I hadn't known that!  However, it seems that there is a further underlying issue here with how the g:select calls the list() function - see above for my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked it out, and here is the solution to anyone else who comes up against the same problem.

The create Subitem page is rendered by means of the Subitem's create.gsp file and the SubitemController.  The trick is to amend the SubitemController **create()** closure:

```
class SubitemController {

def employerService

def create() {
    // this line was the default supplied method:
    // [subitemInstance: new Subitem(params)]
    // so replace with the following:
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [subitemInstance: new Subitem(params), employerInstanceList: employerService.list(params),
     employerInstanceTotal: employerService.count()]
    }
}
```

So now when the SubitemController is asked by the g:select within the Subitem view for the list of Employers, it calls the EmployerService, which supplies the correct answer.  We have simply added 2 further variables that are returned to the view, and which can be referenced anywhere within the view (such as by the g:select tag).

The lesson for me is that the View interacts with the Controller, which can refer to a Service: the Service doesn't play nicely with a View, it seems.